# Are Chdir and Setuid and Setgid thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, go

Are `os. Chdir`, `os.Setuid` and `os.Setgid` thread-safe in Go?

In otherwords, if I do a `os.Chdir` (or the other two functions) in two different goroutines running in parallel, is it going change directory for the working goroutine or the whole process (which can cause problems)?

I couldn't find any information in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the hood, `os.Chdir` just [calls](http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/file.go?s=6108:6136#L201) the `chdir()` system call:

```
   211  func Chdir(dir string) error {
   212      if e := syscall.Chdir(dir); e != nil {
   213          return &PathError{"chdir", dir, e}
   214      }
   215      return nil
   216  }
```

So it affects the entire process. The same is true for `os.Setuid` and `os.Setgid`.

It is probably safe to call these from multiple goroutines at the same time, because executing a system call halts the scheduler; but beware of race conditions.

Comment: @Khash, I believe at the time these system calls were invented, there was no such thing as an OS thread, so the property of current directory is inherently per-process. You might want to rethink your approaches to the problem: say, keep the directory pathname in each goroutine and use `path/filepath` to construct *full* pathnames to operate on for each goroutine when needed. Another way would be to create a helper package wrapping OS-specific syscalls such as [`openat()` of Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/openat) and keep one directory FD per goroutine effectively having "private" cwds.

Comment: @Khan, by the way I see that Go already has `syscall.Openat()` so implementing what I described would be a no-brainier. No cross-platform support, of course, though.

Comment: @Khan, quick googling indicated that recent versions of BSDs have `*at()`, and so does Solaris, but not Darwin yet.

Comment: @Khan, another approach could be to implement a "file opener" goroutine: you would send it a name of a directory, and a file name under it, and a channel to send the response, it would change the directory there, open a file in it, and send you back the result. All parts of your program should use this service then. Somewhat ugly, but safe and cross-platform.

Comment: @kostix openat and friends are in POSIX though, so Darwin will not wait long to implement them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments. I am looking at running a process with exec.Cmd and in some scenarios, I have seen the Dir attribute passed into exec.Command does not take the desired effect, but it might be an issue on my side which I will investigate further. Thanks again

Comment: @kostix, as for your edit on the question title, I have found google struggling with finding Go related topics. With a tag called Go and not Golang, I deliberately put Golang in the question for others to find it easier through search. Especially with many OS related function names being the same across different languages.

Comment: @Khash, I'm acting as per [this guideline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190). Personally, I just open up the main SO page, and in its search entry write "[go] terms to search for" -- works like a charm.  That's what the tag system is for, after all ;-)